# How to fully define relationships between associated Types in Swift?

Tags: swift, constraints, associated-types

I have the following setup in order to define a graph (and subgraphs, aka Clusters):

```
public protocol Node {
    associatedtype C: Cluster where C.N == Self
}

public protocol Edge {
    associatedtype N: Node
}

public protocol Cluster {
    associatedtype N: Node where N.C == Self
    associatedtype C: Cluster where C.N == N, C == Self
}

public protocol Graph {
    associatedtype N: Node where N.C == C
    associatedtype E: Edge where E.N == N
    associatedtype C: Cluster where C.N == N
}
```

My problem is that I cannot define on the Graph two of the constraints. The Swift compiler (at time of writing part of Xcode 11.4.1 gives the following error messages.
The constraint of N cannot be created because "'C' is not a member type of 'Self.N'"
The constraint of C cannot be created because "'N' is not a member type of 'Self.C'"

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question on Swift forum and got a fast reply from Lantua (https://forums.swift.org/u/Lantua/summary)

Redefining the Graph as

```
public protocol Graph {
    associatedtype E: Edge
    typealias N = E.N
    typealias C = N.C
}
```

works!